# Compute the trace of a matrix across all diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I need to compute the trace of a matrix across all its diagonals.  That is, for an nxm matrix, the operation should produce n+m-1 'traces'.  Here is an example program:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

def function_1(A):  
    output=np.zeros(A.shape[0]+A.shape[1]-1)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]+A.shape[1]-1):
        output[i]=np.trace(A,A.shape[1]-1-i)
    return output

A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

function_1(A)
array([  3.,   9.,  18.,  15.,  13.,   8.])
```

My hope is to find a way to replace the loop in the program, since I need to do this computation many times on very large matrices.  One avenue that looks promising is 
to use numpy.einsum, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.  Alternatively I have looked into rewriting the problem entirely with loops in cython:

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def function_2(long [:,:] A):   
    cdef int n=A.shape[0]
    cdef int m=A.shape[1]
    cdef long [::1] output = np.empty(n+m-1,dtype=np.int64)
    cdef size_t l1
    cdef int i,j, k1
    cdef long out

    it_list1=range(m)
    it_list2=range(m,m+n-1)
    for l1 in range(len(it_list1)):
        k1=it_list1[l1]
        i=0
        j=m-1-k1
        out=0
        while (i<n)&(j<m):
            out+=A[i,j]
            i+=1
            j+=1    
        output[k1]=out  
    for l1 in range(len(it_list2)):
        k1=it_list2[l1]
        i=k1-m+1
        j=0
        out=0
        while (i<n)&(j<m):
            out+=A[i,j]
            i+=1
            j+=1
        output[k1]=out  
    return np.array(output)
```

The cython program outperforms the program looping through np.trace:

```
%timeit function_1(A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.7 µs per loop
%timeit function_2(A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.66 µs per loop
```

So, basically I want to get feedback on whether there was a more efficient way to use numpy/scipy routines, or if I have probably achieved the
fastest way using cython.

Comment: I wonder how this would compare: `np.fromiter(map(A.trace, range(A.shape[1]-1, -A.shape[0], -1)), dtype=np.int64)`

Comment: For large matrices the Cython version can be improved in terms of memory access. I.e. loop over the rows instead of the diagonals.

Comment: In case you wanted the traces to wrap instead of being zero-padded, then there would be a nice way of doing this in fourier space, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your Cython function.
Honestly, this is how I'd do it if Cython is an option.

```
import numpy as np
from libc.stdint cimport int64_t as i64
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def all_trace_int64(i64[:,::1] A):
    cdef:
        int i,j
        i64[:] t = np.zeros(A.shape[0] + A.shape[1] - 1, dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            t[A.shape[0]-i+j-1] += A[i,j]
    return np.array(t)
```

This will be significantly faster than the version you give in your question because it iterates over the array in in the order in which it is stored in memory.
For small arrays, the two approaches are nearly the same, though this one is marginally faster on my machine.

I wrote this function so that it requires a C-contiguous array.
If you have a Fortran contiguous array, transpose it, then reverse the order of the output.

This does return the answers in the opposite order from the function shown in your example, so you will need to reverse the order of the array if the order is particularly important.

You may also improve performance by compiling with heavier optimizations.
For example, you could build your Cython code in the IPython notebook with additional compiler flags by replacing

```
%%cython
```

with something like

```
%%cython -c=-O3 -c=-march=native -c=-funroll-loops -f
```

Edit:
When doing this, you will also want to make sure that your values aren't generated by an outer product. If your values come from an outer product, this operation can be combined with the outer product into a single call to `np.convolve`.

Comment: This method the fastest out of all those proposed.  I really appreciate everyone's efforts though - I learned a lot about numpy that I did not know before (especially bincount and strides).  Thanks to everyone for helping out!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stay away from Cython, building a diagonal index array and using `np.bincount` may do the trick:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> rows, cols = a.shape
>>> rows_arr = np.arange(rows)
>>> cols_arr = np.arange(cols)
>>> diag_idx = rows_arr[:, None] - (cols_arr - (cols - 1))
>>> diag_idx
array([[3, 2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2]])
>>> np.bincount(diag_idx.ravel(), weights=a.ravel())
array([  3.,   9.,  18.,  15.,  13.,   8.])
```

By my timings, for your example input, it is 4x faster than your original pure Python method. So I don't think it is going to be faster than your Cython code, but you may want to time it.

Comment: For a 60×10 array, this is 21× faster than the original.

Comment: nice, and it is memory-headache-less.

Comment: For larger arrays doing `diag_idx = rows_arr[:,None] - (cols_arr - cols + 1)` gives a noticeable speedup.

Comment: Good point, edited the answer. I am guessing, but if the array is sufficiently non-square, probably subtracting from the shortest vector would be noticeable as well...

Answer (score 3):

If your matrix shape is sufficiently far away from being square, i.e. if it is tall or wide, then you can use stride tricks efficiently to do this. You can use stride tricks in any case, but it may not be super memory efficient if the matrix is near square.

What you need to do is create a new array view on the same data which is constructed in a way that the step going from one line to the next also causes an increment in the column. This is achieved by changing the strides of the array.

The problem that one needs to take care of lies at the borders of the array, where one needs to zero-pad. If the array is far from being square, this does not matter. If it is square, then we need twice the size of the array to pad.

If you do not need the smaller traces at the edges, then you do not need to zero-pad.

Here goes (assuming more columns than lines, but easily adapted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

A = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)
A_embedded = np.hstack([np.zeros([3, 2]), A, np.zeros([3, 2])])
A = A_embedded[:, 2:-2]  # We are now sure that the memory around A is padded with 0, but actually we never really need A again

new_strides = (A.strides[0] + A.strides[1], A.strides[1])
B = as_strided(A_embedded, shape=A_embedded[:, :-2].shape, strides=new_strides)

traces = B.sum(0)

print A
print B
print traces
```

In order to conform with the output you show in your example, you need to reverse it (see @larsmans comment)

```
traces = traces[::-1]
```

This is a specific example with concrete numbers. If this is useful to your usecase I can turn it into a general function.

Comment: +1, although the output is in reverse order compared to the original. `B.sum(axis=0)[::-1]` solves that.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't notice that. Since I don't see a way of integrating this reverse order in the calculations, I will edit the output as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is competitive if the array is large:

```
def f5(A):
    rows, cols = A.shape
    N = rows + cols -1
    out = np.zeros(N, A.dtype)
    for idx in range(rows):
        out[N-idx-cols:N-idx] += A[idx]
    return out[::-1]
```

Although it uses a Python loop it's faster than the `bincount` solution (for large arrays.. on my system..)

---

This method does have high sensitivity to the array column/row ratio, because this ratio determines how much looping is done in Python relative to Numpy. 
As @Jaime pointed out it's efficient to iterate the smallest dimension, e.g.:

```
def f6(A):
    rows, cols = A.shape
    N = rows + cols -1
    out = np.zeros(N, A.dtype)

    if rows > cols:
        for idx in range(cols):
            out[N-idx-rows:N-idx] += A[:, idx]
    else:
        for idx in range(rows):
            out[N-idx-cols:N-idx] += A[idx]
        out = out[::-1]
    return out
```

But it should be noted that for larger array sizes (e.g. `100000 x 500` on my system) accessing the array row by row as in the first code I posted could still be faster, probably because of how the array is laid out in the RAM
(it's faster to fetch contiguous chunks than spread out bits).

Comment: Yes, I can see that this would work out better when matrices are very wide, but it will depend crucially on the columns/lines ratio, the higher the better.

Comment: @eickenberg; It certainly depends on the col/rows ratio, but it's not _that_ crucial though. In my testing it's faster than @Jaime method even for `A = np.random.rand(100000, 500)`

Comment: Interesting. That should be a different effect then: @Jaime builds a large index array which you avoid with your method. So his method should get worse when data increases in any direction. Whereas yours, at `cols * lines == constant` should do better when `lines >> cols`

Comment: My code became less competitive after @Jaime edited his, but mine performs reasonably still if the column/row ratio isn't too high.

Comment: If you always iterate over the smallest dimension, and have the vectorized sum over the largest, it should perform even better, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jaime, that's indeed the case for smaller matrices. From a certain size it seems to cost too much to access the discontiguous data in the columns and it becomes slower again. At which array size the switch over happens is I'm guessing machine dependent.

Comment: Mysteries of the memory cache... Nice analysis anyway, +1!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by (slightly abusively) using `scipy.sparse.dia_matrix` in two ways, one sparser than the other.

The first one, yielding the exact result, uses the `dia_matrix` stored data vector

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
A = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)
traces = dia_matrix(A).data.sum(1)[::-1]
```

A less memory-intensive method would be to work the other way round:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
A = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)
A_dia = dia_matrix((A, range(len(A))), shape=(A.shape[1],) * 2)
traces = np.array(A_dia.sum(1)).ravel()[::-1]
```

Note however, that two entries are missing in this solution. This may be correctible in a smart way, but I am not sure yet.

---

@moarningsun found the solution:

```
rows, cols = A.shape

A_dia = dia_matrix((A, np.arange(rows)), shape=(cols,)*2)
traces1 = A_dia.sum(1).A.ravel()

A_dia = dia_matrix((A, np.arange(-rows+1, 1)), shape=(rows,)*2)
traces2 = A_dia.sum(1).A.ravel()

traces = np.concatenate((traces1[::-1], traces2[-2::-1]))
```

Comment: Funny how it boils down to "find a C extension that does what you need, regardless of the extension's original purpose" :P I wonder how close this is to the performance of a (nearly optimal) Cython implementation.

Comment: You are right, that is basically what it is. Some of them can even be elegant (not attempting to judge this one, though). If one does it, it should be very useful and have enough advantages in speed/memory etc in order to justify its obscurity. In this case I admit that I have started to see this thread from more of a code golf point of view :)

Answer (score -1):

`np.trace` does what you want:

```
import numpy as np

A = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

n = A.shape[0]
[np.trace(A, i) for i in range(-n+1, n+1)]
```

**Edit**: Changed `np.sum(np.diag())` to `np.trace()` according to the suggestion from @user2357112.

Comment: If you're going to use a list comprehension, `np.trace` already does this even better. The point is to avoid Python-level loops and comprehensions, as they're much slower than you want for this kind of work.

Answer (score -2):

Use the numpy array `trace` method:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
A.trace()
```

returns:

```
15
```